# URL Rewrite IIS7 - Get only first directory after .COM

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I wanted to implement an redirect rule in IIS 7.5 which checks only first directory after .COM.

E.g. 
1. http://www.test.com/ABC , Here i need to get only ABC and pass to other page as query string.

1. http://www.test.com/ABC/XYZ - Skip
2. test.com/ABC/Home.aspx or any other file - Skip

Can anyone provide your valuable suggestion.

Thank You

Comment: I used ^(.*[a-z])/$ as RegExp. This is valid ".com/test/" ".com/test/test1/". So any text ends with "/" is valid. Any other suggestion please; this would be great help for me.

Comment: Hi.. hope someone would have came across this... waiting for any input that helps me...